# Not able to deploy NFT contract on reinkeby .Seems like truffle is not able to decode private key from the mnemonic

Tags: truffle-migration

[image]

Here is the truffle config

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    cldev: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*',
    },
    ganache: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 7545,
      network_id: '*',
    },
    kovan: {
      provider: () => {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, url)
      },
      network_id: '42',
      skipDryRun: true
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () => {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, url)
      },
      network_id: '4',
      skipDryRun: true
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.6.12',
    },
  },
  api_keys: {
    etherscan: '<ETHERSCAN_API_KEY>'
  },
  plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ]
}
```

Comment: What HDWallet version are you using? Newer versions changed how to instantiate it check if that fixes it https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/hdwallet-provider.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yess turns out the problem was with truffle version . use trufflve verions 1.2.3